# Display two items in a ListView, getting setAdapter() on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, android-adapter, simpleadapter

I'm trying to create a ListView with two separate items of TextViews. 
My ListView is a part of content_main.xml (R.id.list), and TextViews are parts of list_item.xml (R.id.textUp, R.id.text2).
The error that I get is a `ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference`. This is how were assigned hashmap and listView in my java code:

```
        private ListView list;
        private HashMap<String, String> associatedItem;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {//LayoutInflater inflater
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_goal_text);
        list = findViewById(R.id.list);
        associatedItem = new HashMap<String, String>();
        ...
```

And the handler:

```
 public void doneButtonHandler(View view) {

    int   day  = picker.getDayOfMonth();
    int   month= picker.getMonth();
    int   year = picker.getYear();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(year,month,day);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy", US);
    String formatedDate = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());

    associatedItem.put(formatedDate, strMssg);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    Iterator it = associatedItem.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        HashMap<String, String> resultsMap = new HashMap<>(2);
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        resultsMap.put("First Line",formatedDate);
        resultsMap.put("Second Line",strMssg);//pair.getValue().toString()
        listItems.add(resultsMap);
    }

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listItems ,R.layout.list_item,
            new String[]{"First Line", "Second Line"},
            new int[]{R.id.textUp, R.id.text2});

    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Error Logcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.gryzhuk.goaltracker.AddGoal.doneButtonHandler(AddGoal.java:134)
```

activity_add_goal_text.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AddGoal"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
        android:text="@string/enter_goal"
        android:textSize="20sp"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <Button
        android:onClick="nextButtonHandler"
        android:id="@+id/next_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="53dp"
        android:text="@string/next_button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/enteredGoalTxt"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/enteredGoalTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="126dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter here"
        android:inputType="textShortMessage"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textUp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorLineUp"
        android:textSize="21sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorLineBottom"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

content_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.teamproblemsolver.fabsubmenu.MainActivity">

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            fab:menu_animationDelayPerItem="50"
            fab:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
            fab:menu_buttonSpacing="0dp"
            fab:menu_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            fab:menu_colorPressed="#c784d3ed"
            fab:menu_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
            fab:menu_fab_hide_animation="@anim/hide_to_bottom"
            fab:menu_fab_show_animation="@anim/show_from_bottom"
            fab:menu_fab_size="normal"
            fab:menu_icon="@drawable/fab_add"
            fab:menu_openDirection="up"
            fab:menu_shadowColor="#66000000"
            fab:menu_shadowRadius="4dp"
            fab:menu_shadowXOffset="1dp"
            fab:menu_shadowYOffset="3dp"
            fab:menu_showShadow="true">


            <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/add_to_list"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add_to_list"
                fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
                fab:fab_colorPressed="#c784d3ed"
                fab:fab_label="Add Goal"
                fab:fab_size="mini" />

        </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check the following method call:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_goal_text)
```

You said, that the list is in the **content_main.xml** but in your code there is no reference to that layout file. Did you want to use this in the call to **setContentView**?
Or is that an included layout or a fragment?

Also, even though it's a bit more complicated to use than listview, **recyclerview** is the new way to go to display a list of items in Android.

Comment: **content_main.xml** is app's home screen where I want to display the output. `R.layout.activity_add_goal_text` and `R.layout.activity_add_goal` are different layouts for user inputs.

Comment: Can you update your logcat error message where you got crashes ?

Comment: Ohh, so you got two activities? One is the home screen that shows the list and the second one to add items to the list, is that correct? If so, then you need to change your approach, in Android each Acticity is tied to a layout through setContentView. Activity A cannot access views from Activity B. That is why your findViewById(R.id.list) returns null. To get your list from one to the other Activity, you should probably use some sort of persistence layer (Room for example). One Activity writes to the persistence layer and another reads from it.

Comment: @lukas.bloder yes, there are 2 different layouts for user input and the third one `content_main.xml` for output which is also a home screen. Should I use inflate() method in order to put my info into `content_main.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

Check this line in your view

```
associatedItem = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

and this one in your `doneButtonHandler()` method

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

and in your `adapter`

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listItems ,R.layout.list_item,
            new String[]{"First Line", "Second Line"},
            new int[]{R.id.textUp, R.id.text2});
```

so what `listItems` get here? if `associatedItem` has no items.

also make sure this is inflated in your view

```
 list = findViewById(R.id.list);
```

and check line 134 in your `AddGoal.java` and put debugger which will help you to find the problem.

As per your updated view the problem is with your  `list = findViewById(R.id.list);` which is not inflated in your activity so `list` throws null object reference error which is set for adapter `list.setAdapter(adapter)` . Only solution is to change your implementation approach either inflate another view programmatically or modify your layout to use listview in your activity layout.

Comment: `associatedItem` has data entered by user in `R.layout.activity_add_goal_text` and `R.layout.activity_add_goal` layouts. There is `associatedItem.put(formatedDate, strMssg)` for this - the output of this hashmap was correct.

Comment: 134 in AddGoal.java is `list.setAdapter(adapter)` which is setAdapter() on a null object reference

Comment: So that means your list which is listview is not inflated can you post your  layout code of  (R.layout.activity_add_goal_text).

Comment: R.layout.activity_add_goal_text doesn't contain listView

Comment: Ok so I posted few more xml files

Comment: Yep the problem is inflating views because your content_main.xml is not inflated so your  list = findViewById(R.id.list); wont be inflated at all hence you got the null object reference error.

Answer (score 0):

problem is `setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_goal_text)`
you have't put listview in R.layout.activity_add_goal_text

that's why you are facing null pointer exception

**put listview in R.layout.activity_add_goal_text**

hope it works